# SQL window function by column value and not by rows

Tags: sql, windowing

I am trying to create a flag that looks back 7 days for a date column and if there is a row within that partition then true if there is no row returned within that 7 days then false.

Can a window function accomplish this? most windowing function seem to operate on rows and not column values.

checkout sample data
There are a bunch of messeage_ids and then has an event of open then a timestamp. for each row i need to look back 604800 seconds and see if any rows exist within the message_id partition.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffpk2.png)

Comment: I think you don't need a window function for this. Please provide sample data and desired output (pictures are not considered samples, samples are text, code or fiddle). Also tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for many databases:

```
select sg_message_id, event, t1.timestamp, 
  case when t1.timestamp - previous.timestamp < 604800 
  then true else false end as hasRecent
from myTable t1, 
 lateral (select timestamp 
          from myTable t2 
          where t1.sg_message_id = t2.sg_message_id
               and t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp
          order by t2.timestamp desc
          limit 1) previous(timestamp);
```

If you want to use window functions, then look at lead(). With lead() it would look like:

```
    with data as 
(
   select sg_message_id, event, timestamp, 
      lead(timestamp) over (partition by sg_message_id order by timestamp desc) as previousTimeStamp
)
   select sg_message_id, event, timestamp, 
          case when timestamp - previousTimestamp < 604800 
      then true else false end as hasRecent
    from data;
```

Comment: there needs to be a rolling 7 day window. using lead or lag just looks 1 row away and see if its greater than 7 days, i need to look at 7 days worth of rows and see if there are rows or not.

Comment: @JamesCode, lead() supports an offset parameter, if you give sample data, then I could give you the exact code. BTW you still didn't tag your database. And another solution is to use the row_number() windowing function. Just give the sample data and tag the database please.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example.

```
SELECT
    message_id,
    event_timestamp,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM your_table AS t2
            WHERE t2.message_id = t1.message_id
              AND t2.event = 'open'
              AND t2.event_timestamp >= t1.event_timestamp - INTERVAL 7 DAY
              AND t2.event_timestamp < t1.event_timestamp
        ) THEN true
        ELSE false
    END AS flag
FROM your_table AS t1
WHERE event = 'open';
```

Regards,